# Change image layout and position from java code

Tags: java, android

I have this code in `xml` file for an image:

```
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/moneybag"
        android:src="@drawable/bee"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

I am uploading new image on click..

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_CODE && resultCode == EditProfileActivity.RESULT_OK) {
        Log.d("CameraDemo", "Pic saved");

        File imgFile = new  File(dir+"123.jpg");

        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
        cus_profile_pic.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
    }
}
```

**Everything is working except image size.** I am getting large image after capturing image from camera. What should I do to get image on the same place with same width and height (as shown in xml).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For setting image size create a layoutParams  , If your imageView parent is a LinearLayout so you should do this :

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = imageView.getLayoutParams();
lp.width = lastImageWidth;
lp.height = lastImageHeight;
imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

If is RelativeLayout So use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout in above example

Comment: I want to set image parameters from java after uploading new image. I am replacing old image with new one. So, I want same positioning just like before. I don't want image in center.

Comment: Get last image's width and height programmatically before replacing it , Then replace image and set last image width and height to it , also set the scaleType to centerCrop

Comment: I don't know how to set it. Can you please put some code to set those parameters?

Comment: I edited my answer , Please take a look at it and let me know if you  have other question :)

Comment: I tried it.. it works. But, it's cutting actual image. I am trying to find the way to reduce the size. as well.

Comment: Set scaleType to fitXY

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

in the xml?

Comment: after I take picture . it's not keeping it's default parameters. When I replace that image with new image. It's coming as large image.

Answer (score 0):

This will also change according to the test device you are using. So your problem is not just about how big is the image. Photo resolution, device screen density and physical screen size will vary. Thus position and size of your image will change.

ImageView or ImageButton renders the image within itself but it also depends on the resolution of the image. So think about putting a bitmap to a smaller container(imageview or imagebutton), container will try to scale down the image to fit its dimensions or screen dimensions. This scale down should also preserve the aspect ratio of the image according to selected scaleType.

So you can do these things:
1) Scale down the bitmap before putting it to imageview

2) Rather then saying wrap content give specific dimensions

3) Make width match_parent and put another (maybe transparent) dummy view to its side and make height 0dp and make adjustViewBounds property true. (0 dp means that height is dynamic according to content to preserve aspect ratio)

4) Change scaleType to CENTER_INSIDE